# How can I avoid the error, that the .pdb cannot be written?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Working with Visual Studio 2008, I got sometimes the error, that the pdb-file cannot be actualized. it was no big problem, I deleted it and made a new build and everything was fine. Now this error comes multiple times a day, and it get annoying. That can be the reason and how get I rid of it?

Comment: Where/how is the PDF file stored? Is it just stored in your local filesystem? Or is this some kind of share or network filesystem?

Comment: Not pdf, the Debug-database pdb.

Comment: Sorry, I meant PDB. I guess I type PDF a lot more than PDB and my fingers were on auto-pilot. :)

Comment: In the project in the same directory as the output-binary this file is placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .pdb cannot be written if it is in use by another program.

I can see 3 possibilities as to how this can happen :

1. Two instances of Visual Studio 2008 are working on the same project (unlikely, I know)
2. Some source control plug-in in Visual Studio 2008 has decided to also manage
   the .pdb, so one needs to delete the reference to it in that plug-in.
3. Some files included in the solution are missing, so one needs to remove their references (ie. the files with the warning sign).

Comment: Would an anti-virus also cause this locking?

Comment: @RandolphWest: Yes, it could, but this condition normally clears up almost immediately so that the pdb becomes very quickly again updateable.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense.